# Analytics - Multiple authors

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tags, universal-analytics

We are making the switch to Universal Analytics, the code below defines the author in the new tracking code.

```
script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-x', 'example.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview', { 'dimension1': '<?=$author?>'});
</script>
```

The question is, if we have several authors, do we need to define them individually as a custom dimensions (1,2,3..etc) and pass each dimension via the pageview send?

Also, what about tracking events? For example, tracking errors on a form:

```
ga('send', 'Event', 'Signup Form', 'First Name', 'Error Code Desc', {'nonInteraction': 1}”
```

Is this put in the tracking code too? Or in the code for the form?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a custom dimension per autor (you would run out of custom dimension pretty quickly, there are only 20 slots for custom dimensions and metric). Just create a custom dimension "authors" within "hit" scope (there is a dropdown with three settings hit, session, visitor in the custom definitions->custom dimensions interface, author is a property if the current page so you chose "hit") and pass the authors name.

Events are used to track interactions that do not result in pageviews or content changes, so usually you'd put them in a javascript callback function for whatever event you want to track. Your example looks like it is supposed to store form errors, so it would go in the (clientsie) validation function for that form. Just make sure there is a tracker (a call to ga('create')) somewhere in the page before your event (usually the standard pageview tracking code will already have created a tracker object so that shouldn't be a problem).

Comment: Thanks @Eike, i didn't know about the limit of 20 slots. I understand setting the "authors" custom dimension. If i pass the $author variable through the snippet ga('send', 'pageview', { 'dimension1': '<?=$author?>'}); will i be able to create reports for each author using custom reports or is there some other way?

Answer (score 0):

So I had a quick read through of the Google Docs regarding this, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

As far as I can tell, you will need to define each one as a custom dimension and send those.
(Bottom of the page that I linked).

I'm not too sure about the second question regarding tracking errors on a form, I'm sure someone else who perhaps knows a bit more about that can help.